# Is MySQL Query framed properly?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm attempting to run the following Query on an AWS ec2 xlarge instance:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE 3 SELECT * FROM TABLE 2 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE1);
```

I attempted using ec2 as I thought perhaps it was my laptop making the query taking long as Table1 has 14000 rows and 6 columns and table 2 has around 1 million rows and 11 columns. However I get:

Write failed: Broken pipe

When using the aws instance, and DBMS timeout on my laptop.

Should the Query be taking > than these timeout triggers? Anyway to word the query better?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Did I not frame the question correctly?

Comment: there are strange peple that donwvote without motivation  ,... don't worry

Comment: fair enough just want to make sure I didn't break any forum rules

Comment: No ... your question .. is correct and correctly .. proposed ..  sometimes .. someone .. take a look and downvote without motivation ..  .. patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is very poor at executing `WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT table2.id ...)`. It's better to use a `JOIN`.

```
CREATE TABLE Table3
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 AS t2
JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: do I have to select all the rows (t1.*) if I just want the ID column?

Comment: You should select whichever columns you want to put in `Table3`. I used `SELECT t1.*` because your question has `SELECT *`.

Comment: I had `Table1` and `Table2` backwards from your question, I've fixed that.

Comment: It has been 10+ minutes and the process is still running, is this typical behavior for MySQL?

Comment: Make sure both tables have indexes on the `id` column.

Comment: Ok, is index only possible for non repeating ids? Table 2 may have multiple instances of a single ID from table 1.

Comment: You can have either `INDEX` or `UNIQUE INDEX`. The latter doesn't allow repetitions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125456/discussion-between-stacks-of-overflow-and-barmar).

Comment: I don't, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try split logically the query

```
CREATE TABLE3 
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE1 where id between 1 and 10000);
```

and then

```
insert into table3
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE1 where id between 10001 and 20000);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: USE CT -A;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Comment: When I execute that it still takes forever to open the database... as this is a fairly powerful instance is this sort of behavior normal for MySQL?

Comment: @Stacksofoverflow  i don't understand your comment .. please explain better

Comment: my apologies, there were some background processes that had to be killed

Comment: I've selected an answer but I thank you for your time!